# How to get SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints for Android app when using Play App Signing?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I uploaded an Android app with Play App Signing and am now trying to get it's SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints.

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) state that you can find the fingerprints in the Google Play Console on the Release > Setup > App Integrity page, but as far as I can tell, this page does not exist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Manually**

Open the Google Play Console then select the app you want and then you can find the **Play App Signing** page under `Release > Setup > App Integrity`.

Below is a screenshot:

[image: play app signing]

**Automatically**

You can navigate directly to the **Play App Signing** page using the below Google Play Console Keymanagement Url:

https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/keymanagement

It will prompt you to select the app first you are interested to and then it will redirect you to the Play App Signing page for the selected app.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot! I had misunderstood what the "Release" category was.

Comment: Thank you! This screen finished my 2 days straying.

Comment: Meaning, to get rid of the issue with "W/NetworkRequest( 7340): No App Check token for request" I have to pay the $25 in order to get the SHA 256 fingerprint?

Comment: Why is this nowhere documented or just mentioned?! Thank you very much!